# BeforeCreate hook for postgre not hashing password using bcryptjs

Tags: node.js, hook, sequelize.js, bcrypt

```
const userModel = connection.define('user', {
user_id: {
  type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
user_name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  unique: true
},
email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  unique: true
},
password: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING
}
},
{
hooks: {
  beforeCreate: () =>{
    console.log("hook called");
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      const passwordHash = bcrypt.hash(userModel.password, salt);
      userModel.password = passwordHash;
      console.log('simple pass', userModel.password);
      console.log('hashed password', passwordHash);
      return resolve(userModel);
    });


  }
}
});
```

It returns this error. 
hook called
simple pass Promise {  }
hashed password Promise {  }
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "users" ("user_id","user_name","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'deaehrddjelltariq','ddehreejd@gmail.com','abcd','2018-02-15 00:17:51.272 +00:00','2018-02-15 00:17:51.272 +00:00') RETURNING *;
(node:13686) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, object
    at _async (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at /Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:223:17
    at new Promise ()
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:222:20)
    at Promise (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/models/user.js:29:37)
    at new Promise ()
    at Function.beforeCreate (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/models/user.js:27:14)
    at Promise.each.hook (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/hooks.js:130:35)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Object.gotValue (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:18)
    at Object.gotAccum (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:144:25)
    at Object.tryCatcher (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/mfaisal/NodeProjects/chaffer/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
(node:13686) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13686) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: please see that I get "simple pass Promise { }" for "console.log('simple pass, userModel.password);" and similar of passwordHash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `hook` with this :

With the help of `hashSync` there is no need of `promise`

```
beforeCreate : (user , options) => {
    {
        console.log("hook called");

        //const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = user.password && user.password != "" ? bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10) : "";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a minor change. I don't why but "bcrypt.hashSync" was throwing illegal argument exception with 'Salt' in the arguments. I replaced it with an integer and now it works fine.